# Get a range of numbers around a given number

Tags: javascript

I need to preload some images, so based on the current slide index, I need to preload the previous and next images.

For example, if the currentIndex is `23`, and range is set to `2`, then all the pages to preload would be `21,22,23,24,25`. If currentIndex is `0` then it would be `0,1,2`

```js
let initial = 0,
    pages = Array.from({ length: 50 }, (_, i) => i);

console.log(pages);

// Approach #1: returns a fixed length array with potentially undefined values
let preloadPages1 = Array.from([-2, -1, 0, +1, +2], v => {
    let n = initial + v;
    return pages[n];
});
console.log(preloadPages1);

// Approach #2: works, but too verbose
let preloadPages2 = [];
for (let i = initial - 2; i <= initial + 2; i++) {
    if (pages[i] === undefined) continue;
    preloadPages2.push(pages[i]);
}
console.log(preloadPages2);
```

I wonder if there's a better more elegant way to do this?

Comment: This seems to be more a question for Code Review  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can pages only be between 0 to 50?

Comment: @AlexL No, could be anything. 50 is just an example.

Comment: Ok perfect, then now my answer is very generic and should solve all use cases: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60600670/9792594

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let initial = 0,
    pages = Array.from({ length: 50 }, (_, i) => i);

// Suggestion #1
let preload1 = [];
for (let i = initial - 2; i <= initial + 2; i++) {
  if (i in pages) preload1.push(pages[i]);
}

// Suggestion #2
let preload2 = pages
  .slice(Math.max(initial-2, 0), initial+3)
  .filter(p => p !== undefined);
```

Comment: `i in pages` ? I can't find anything about the `in` on MDN. I know about `includes` though.

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: The `in` operator is one of the oldest operators in JS. Supported by IE since IE 5.5

Comment: `If you set a property to undefined but do not delete it, the in operator returns true for that property.`

Comment: Thanks, good to know about it, but doesn't seem useful for my current requirement.

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned that, sry. But you can use `delete pages[i]` instead of setting things to undefined (set variabels and indizes to `undefined` is bad code style btw., you should use `null` for that) and then use the `in`.

Answer (score 1):

What about this? It's a very generic approach using ES6 map and filter:

```js
function generateArray(initial, offset, min, max){
  let temp_arr = [];
  for (let i = -offset; i <= offset; i++){
    temp_arr.push(i);
  }
  
  const modified_arr = temp_arr.map((child, index) => {
    return initial + child;
  })
  
  return modified_arr.filter((val) => val >= min && val < max);
  // min and max define the filter here
}

console.log(generateArray(0,2,0,50));
console.log(generateArray(23,2,0,50));
console.log(generateArray(49,2,0,50));
```

OR we could combine map and filter by using reduce

(and note the alternative 1-liner to create the temp_arr):

```js
function generateArray(initial, offset, min, max){
  
  let temp_arr = [...Array(2 * offset + 1).keys()].map(i => i - offset);

  return temp_arr.reduce((agg_arr, child) => {
    if (initial + child >= min && initial + child < max){
      agg_arr.push(initial + child)
    }
    return agg_arr;
  }, [])
}

console.log(generateArray(0,2,0,50));
console.log(generateArray(23,2,0,50));
console.log(generateArray(49,2,0,50));
```

Although this is shorter and would be slightly faster (iterates over the array once in the reduce rather than twice in the map followed by filter) but I think the first approach is more readable and so if performance is not critical (i.e. the array is never huge), then I would go with the first for readability and clarity.

Same goes for the for-loop versus the one-liner to generate the temp_arr

We could also make it even more generic by replacing min and max with one filter_function argument, and then using this function to test if the element meets the condition(s)

That could look like this:

```js
function generateArray(initial, offset, filter_func){
  let temp_arr = [];
  for (let i = -offset; i <= offset; i++){
    temp_arr.push(i);
  }
  
  const modified_arr = temp_arr.map((child, index) => {
    return initial + child;
  })
  
  return modified_arr.filter(filter_func);
}

const filter_func = (val) => val >= 0 && val < 50;

console.log(generateArray(0,2,filter_func));
console.log(generateArray(23,2,filter_func));
console.log(generateArray(49,2,filter_func));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could slice the array and take a slingl slice if bothe new indices are insife of the lenght of the array or take two slices.

```js
function getValues(array, padding, index) {
    var length = array.length,
        left = index - padding,
        right = index + padding + 1;
    return left >= 0 && right < length
        ? array.slice(left, right)
        : [
            ...array.slice((left + length) % length, length),
            ...array.slice(0, right % length)
        ];
}

let initial = 0,
    pages = Array.from({ length: 50 }, (_, i) => i),
    padding = 2;

console.log(...getValues(pages, padding, 0));
console.log(...getValues(pages, padding, 2));
console.log(...getValues(pages, padding, 49));
```